# Purpose of $ \frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}$ while driving "Schwarz- Christoffel Formula"

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am studying "Schwarz-Christoffel Formula" while driving this formula they are using term $\displaystyle \frac{f''(z)}{f'(z)}$, i have an idea that this term is somewhere is used in Schwarz derivative but still i am not getting a complete picture of why they are using this? i'm also attaching a derivation where they are using this. (**The underline part**)

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai  "Conformal mapping" by "Zeev Nehari".

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood. The point is suppose you replace $f(z) \to a f(z) + b$, then the quantity $\frac{f''(z) }{f'(z)}$ is the same. However this is useless in the section you highlighted because it talk about circular arc, there we need another quantity which is invariant under Moebius transformations

Comment: Thankyou for the help, i think i got this now.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFHnGttdgJg

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai i have already watched this video, such an amazing explanation. : )

Comment: https://asset-pdf.scinapse.io/prod/567060304/567060304.pdf also see this